# How to use TemplateBinding in Path.Data?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, templatebinding

How can I bind a property inside `Path.Data` to a `TemplateBinding`? I noticed that in this following example, the properties `SegmentColor` and `StrokeThickness` are set and updated correctly, but not the property `TargetPoint`. Further testing seems to confirm the issue seems to be related to the property being nested in an element of `Path.Data`. The following code tries to simplify the context which I am facing while creating the template for a custom control.

C#:

```
public class TestProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public Brush SegmentColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(SegmentColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SegmentColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public Point TargetPoint
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(TargetPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetPointProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StrokeThickness), typeof(double), typeof(TestProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SegmentColor), typeof(Brush), typeof(TestProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetPointProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetPoint), typeof(Point), typeof(TestProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata());
}
```

Xaml:

```
<c:TestProgressBar StrokeThickness="15"
                   TargetPoint="100,0">
    <c:TestProgressBar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type c:TestProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:TestProgressBar}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path
                                  Stroke="{TemplateBinding SegmentColor}"
                                  StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}"
                                  Width="100" Height="100">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure>
                                            <LineSegment Point="{TemplateBinding TargetPoint}"/>
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </c:TestProgressBar.Style>
</c:TestProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using TemplateBindings within the Path.Data causes the issue. Replacing it with a TemplatedParent Binding fixes the issue:

```
<LineSegment Point="{Binding TargetPoint, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

I can't quite explain why this is, though. In my original code, I am using readonly dependency properties, so the issue can't be linked to TwoWay binding problems (as I've hard can be the case with TemplateBinding).

I know that Binding using TemplatedParent is runtime-evaluated, as opposed to compile-time for TemplateBinding, so perhaps something along those lines fixes the binding.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is a little known detail about `TemplateBinding`, they [do not work on properties `Freezable`s](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c13e7729-8290-4df0-a6fb-23f4cc7c79c0/templatebinding-not-working?forum=wpf). In fact, a [`LineSegment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.linesegment?view=netcore-3.1) indirectly derives from `Freezable` as you can see in its inheritance hierarchy.

> Object -> DispatcherObject -> DependencyObject -> **Freezable** -> Animatable -> PathSegment -> LineSegment

However, `Path` does not and that is why `TemplateBinding`s on its properties work. As a template binding is just an optimized **but limited** version of a `Binding`, you can always [use its binding syntax equivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#remarks) that does not come with any limitations and will also work on `Freezable`s.

```
<LineSegment Point="{Binding TargetPoint, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Note, that the `Mode` is set to `OneWay` here, to point out that `TemplateBinding`s are always one-way and this is the equivalent `Binding`, but bindings are more powerful and support any binding mode.

> I am using readonly dependency properties, so the issue can't be linked to TwoWay binding problems (as I've hard can be the case with TemplateBinding).

A dependency property declaration must be read-only, but that does not make the dependency property read-only itself, that is done by declaring a dependency property key and using the `RegisterReadOnly` method.

- [Read-Only Dependency Properties / Creating Custom Read-Only Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/read-only-dependency-properties?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details! This is very good to know. About the readonly dependency properties, what you described is exactly what I did and meant. It just wasn't in the example I provided so i understand the confusion.